# Protect XML Parser against XEE attacks

Tags: xml, security

I saw that we could configure an XMLReader with .setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true)

This feature is documented by : "Feature for secure processing. true instructs the implementation to process XML securely. This may set limits on XML constructs to avoid conditions such as denial of service attacks. 
"

I wanted to test it with the following code:

```
    XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
    reader.setContentHandler(handler);
    reader.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
    reader.parse(input);
```

and giving it the billion laughs attack to parse:

```
    String DOS = new String("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE lolz [\n<!ENTITY lol \"lol\">\n<!ELEMENT lolz (#PCDATA)>\n<!ENTITY lol1 \"&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;\">\n<!ENTITY lol2 \"&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;&lol1;\">\n<!ENTITY lol3 \"&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;\">\n<!ENTITY lol4 \"&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;\">\n<!ENTITY lol5 \"&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;\">\n<!ENTITY lol6 \"&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;\">\n<!ENTITY lol7 \"&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;\">\n<!ENTITY lol8 \"&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;\">\n<!ENTITY lol9 \"&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;\">\n]>\n<lolz>&lol9;</lolz>");
```

First, I got the JAXP00010001 error: Message: JAXP00010001: The parser has encountered more than "64000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the JDK. And the error was the same when putting the SECURE feature to false.

So I've set the jvm arg : -Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit=0, to disable the expansion limit from the virtual machine. Then, re run the test with the SECURE_FEATURE to true.

But now, when I run the program, it doesn't seem to be protected against this attack, it just keeps running.

I'm running under jdk1.8.0_60.

Anyone can explain what is happening? What does .setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true) actually do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/limits.html "A value less than or equal to 0 indicates no limit" so you need to set "A positive integer" to indicate a concrete limit.

Comment: Ok, but what is the purpose of using .setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true) then?